# MongoDB NodeJS error: assert.equal(3, result.result.n) not working. Giving error "Cannot read property 'n' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to MongoDB and have just started setting up the insert document function in my js file. This is the code I copied from the documentation:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'FruitsDB';
const client = new MongoClient(url, {useNewUrlParser: true});

// Use connect method to connect to the server
client.connect(function(err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  insertDocuments(db, function() {
    client.close();
  });
});

const insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  const collection = db.collection('fruits');
  // Insert some documents
  collection.insertMany([
    {a : 1}, {a : 2}, {a : 3}
  ], function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    assert.equal(3, result.result.n);
    assert.equal(3, result.ops.length);
    console.log("Inserted 3 documents into the collection");
    callback(result);
  });
}
```

It gives an error saying "Cannot read property 'n' of undefined". Can someone help me out?

Comment: Your program works fine as it is. I just tried and it created a database called as `FruitsDB`, and inserted 3 documents in the `fruits` collection. I am using MongoDB v4.2, NodeJS v12.18, and MongoDB NodeJS Driver v3.6.

Answer (score 8):

Replacing

```
    assert.equal(3, result.result.n);
    assert.equal(3, result.ops.length);
```

with

```
    assert.equal(3,result.insertedCount);
    assert.equal(3,Object.keys(result.insertedIds).length);
```

will do the magic.

According to the latest MongoDB Nodejs driver's documentation, the `collection.insertMany()` returns a Promise of type `InsertManyResult`. See the following api documentations [link1](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/classes/collection.html#insertmany) and [link2](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/interfaces/insertmanyresult.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Hey it seems that we are following the same tutorial:
I'm using node v14.17.3 and mongodb 5.0.1

Commenting out is the only solution i found for the moment to get the needed console output:

```
//assert.equal(3, result.result.n);
//assert.equal(3, result.ops.length);
```

console output:

```
Connected successfully to server
Inserted 3 documents into the collection
```

Answer (score 0):

If you comment it out, then even if you insert 2,3 or 4 number of documents it will still log "Inserted 3 documents into the collection"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while back, an easy way to still check for errors is to replace the assertion with a simple if statement. You can try to replace the assertions with an if statement as shown below;

```
assert.equal(err, null);
assert.equal(3, result.result.n);
assert.equal(3, result.ops.length);
```

with

```
function(err, result) {
if(err) throw err;
```